# Exercises of norms on $C([0,1])$ and $L^2([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I apologize for the title, i did not know how to express in a right way.

Show that:

1. $C([0,1])\subset L^2([0,1])$.
2. Given $f\in C([0,1])$ and the norm $\| \cdot\|_2$ in $L^2([0,1])$, show that
   $$\|f\|_2=0\Longrightarrow f(x)=0,\quad \forall x\in[0,1].$$

I tried

1. Let $f\in C([0,1])$, then $f$ is continuous and therefor integrable, hence $f^2$ is also integrable, so
   $\|f\|_2=\left(\displaystyle\int_0^1|f(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2}<\infty$, 
   and taking equivalence class
   $\|[f]\|_2:=\|f\|_2<\infty$

Therfore, $[f]\in L^2([0,1])$.

2. If $\|[f]\|_2=0$, then $\|f\|_2=0$ this means that $f=0$ almost everywhere, and how can I proof from this that $f=0$

Are they correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

First part is correct.

If $f$ is continuous and $f=0$ a.e. then then there is a set $E$ of measure $0$ such that $f(x)=0$ whenever $x \notin E$. Now there cannot be any open interval contained in $E$ since $E$ has measure $0$. This translates to the fac that $E^{c}$ is dense. So if $x \in [0,1]$ there exist $(x_n) \subset E^{c}$ such that $x_n \to x$. But then $f(x)=\lim f(x_n)=\lim 0=0$.

Comment: thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Quite often one is required to show $X\subseteq Y$ as a topological embedding rather than simply an inclusion as sets, in this case, it is not hard to see that $\|f\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}\leq\|f\|_{L^{\infty}[0,1]}=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$, so the topological embedding is then established.

Comment: Thank you very much.